# Unable to create a source for reading table error when trying to query a glue table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I'm new to kinesis analytics studio using apache flink, basically I have a data stream with hundreds of records going through it, and I want to make some real-time basic analysis, so I went through  [this tutorial](https://www.stackovercloud.com/2021/05/27/introducing-amazon-kinesis-data-analytics-studio-quickly-interact-with-streaming-data-using-sql-python-or-scala/) and created a table in glue using below code:

```
%flink.ssql(type=update)
CREATE TABLE active_users(
user_id varchar(120),
platform varchar(60),
event_time timestamp(3),
WATERMARK FOR event_time AS event_time - INTERVAL '5' SECOND
 )
 PARTITIONED BY (user_id)
 WITH (
'connector' = 'kinesis',
'stream' = 'stream-id',
'aws.region' = 'us-east-1',
'scan.stream.initpos' = 'LATEST',
'format' = 'json',
'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601');
```

and the table was created successfully and I can see it in glue data catalogue, but when I try to query the table with a basic select statement

```
%flink.ssql(type=update)
SELECT * FROM active_users limit 10;
```

I get below error

```
Unable to create a source for reading table 'hive.stream-id.active_users'.

Table options are:

'aws.region'='us-east-1'
'connector'='kinesis'
'format'='json'
'json.timestamp-format.standard'='ISO-8601'
'scan.stream.initpos'='LATEST'
'stream'='stream-id'
```

I looked into the IAM policy and everything looks good, any thoughts on how to tackle this?.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that I tried to solve that issue when I encountered.

1. The versión of flink. I changed it to 1.11 and
2. The IAM policies, have to add them manually:

   ```
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor00",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "kinesis:DescribeStream",
            "kinesis:PutRecord",
            "kinesis:PutRecords",
            "kinesis:GetShardIterator",
            "kinesis:GetRecords",
            "kinesis:ListShards",
            "kinesis:DescribeStreamSummary",
            "kinesis:RegisterStreamConsumer"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:kinesis:eu-west-1:376596651109:stream/edwarinputstream"
        ]
    },
   ```

Once I did the above it ran properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-json</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```